# checkbox label overlapping the checkbox

Tags: php, css, checkbox, yii

I'm doing PHP project using YII framework. I have apply css style for checkbox but the issue is that text for the label is overlapping the checkbox. so if someone can help I will really appreciate it.

Here is my css

```
input[type=checkbox]{
    position: static;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-left: 0;
    display: none;
    border: none !important;
    box-shadow: none !important;
}

input[type=checkbox] + label{
    display: block;
    color: #595a5b;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background:#595a5b;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked + label{
    background: #3e97eb;
    content: '\f14a';
    color: #595a5b;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
}
```

And Here is the code for render the checkbox

```
return array(   
            'action'=>url("/xsearch/location"),
            'elements' => array(
                'label'=> $this->t('<h3 style="border-bottom: solid #DDDDDD 1px;color: #0a0a0a;margin-left: 0px;">Location</h3>'),
                'location'=>array(
                    "type"=>"checkboxlist",
                    "items"=>$locations,
                    'layout' => "{label}\n<fieldset>{input}</fieldset>\n{hint}",
                ),
            ),
            'id' => 'go-to-top-location',
            'model' => $this->model,
        );
```

**Here is my current view**

[image]

**EDIT 1**

Here is rendred html code.

```
<div class="row field_location">
<label for="MXsearchForm_location">Location:</label>
<fieldset><input id="ytMXsearchForm_location" type="hidden" value="" name="MXsearchForm[location]"><input id="MXsearchForm_location_0" value="11" type="checkbox" name="MXsearchForm[location][]"> <label for="MXsearchForm_location_0">test</label><br>
<input id="MXsearchForm_location_1" value="1" checked="checked" type="checkbox" name="MXsearchForm[location][]"> <label for="MXsearchForm_location_1">Colombo</label><br>
<input id="MXsearchForm_location_2" value="2" type="checkbox" name="MXsearchForm[location][]"> <label for="MXsearchForm_location_2">Gampaha</label><br>
<input id="MXsearchForm_location_3" value="3" type="checkbox" name="MXsearchForm[location][]"> <label for="MXsearchForm_location_3">kandy</label><br>
<input id="MXsearchForm_location_4" value="16" type="checkbox" name="MXsearchForm[location][]"> <label for="MXsearchForm_location_4">kegalla</label><br>
<input id="MXsearchForm_location_5" value="7" type="checkbox" name="MXsearchForm[location][]"> <label for="MXsearchForm_location_5">Kurunegala</label><br>
<input id="MXsearchForm_location_6" value="12" type="checkbox" name="MXsearchForm[location][]"> <label for="MXsearchForm_location_6">abc</label></fieldset>
</div>
```

Comment: if possibly  then put html code .

Comment: set `margin-right` to your `input[type="checkbox"]`

Comment: I already set margin-right in my code @Nitin

Comment: what you mean put html code ? in which place ? @Sumitpatel

Answer (score 0):

Give left padding to your label almost same of width of your checkbox image.

label {padding-left: /*width of your checkbox image*/}

Comment: if i give padding-left checkbox size increase

Comment: can you post the HTML code or link of you live code.

Comment: that's a private project. @TrickyUI

Comment: ok.. please post html code of the image you posted in your question.

Comment: I added my rendered html code segment. @Vikash Chauhan

Comment: you can also take help from this blog https://trickyui.blogspot.in/2016/04/custom-checkbox-or-radio-buttons.html

Comment: https://trickyui.blogspot.in/2016/04/custom-checkbox-or-radio-buttons.html